# Why does the documentation of std::ptr::read state that ptr::copy_nonoverlapping "could trigger undefined behavior"?

Tags: memory, rust

The documentation of [`std::ptr::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read.html) has this example code:

> Manually implement [`mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html):
>
> ```rust
> use std::ptr;
>
> fn swap<T>(a: &mut T, b: &mut T) {
>     unsafe {
>         // Create a bitwise copy of the value at `a` in `tmp`.
>         let tmp = ptr::read(a);
>
>         // Exiting at this point (either by explicitly returning or by
>         // calling a function which panics) would cause the value in `tmp` to
>         // be dropped while the same value is still referenced by `a`. This
>         // could trigger undefined behavior if `T` is not `Copy`.
>
>         // Create a bitwise copy of the value at `b` in `a`.
>         // This is safe because mutable references cannot alias.
>         ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(b, a, 1);
>
>         // As above, exiting here could trigger undefined behavior because
>         // the same value is referenced by `a` and `b`.
>
>         // Move `tmp` into `b`.
>         ptr::write(b, tmp);
>
>         // `tmp` has been moved (`write` takes ownership of its second argument),
>         // so nothing is dropped implicitly here.
>     }
> }
>
> let mut foo = "foo".to_owned();
> let mut bar = "bar".to_owned();
>
> swap(&mut foo, &mut bar);
>
> assert_eq!(foo, "bar");
> assert_eq!(bar, "foo");
> ```

I concern about this part:

> ```
>     ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(b, a, 1);
>
>     // As above, exiting here could trigger undefined behavior because
>     // the same value is referenced by `a` and `b`.
> ```

In my opinion, `a: &mut T` and `b: &mut T` point to two different blocks of memory. Why does it say "the same value is referenced by `a` and `b`", then to trigger undefined behavior? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

I missed an important annotation:

```rust
// Create a bitwise copy of the value at `a` in `tmp`.
let tmp = ptr::read(a);

// #################### Marked by me
// Exiting at this point (either by explicitly returning or by
// calling a function which panics) would cause the value in `tmp` to
// be dropped while the same value is still referenced by `a`. This
// could trigger undefined behavior if `T` is not `Copy`.
// #################### Marked by me
```

It is operating on some data of type `T` which may hold managed resource (such as memory on the heap, file handles, etc.) and not be `Copy` (such as `String`), so this bitwise copy operation would result in two `T` data holders sharing the common resource, which could trigger undefined behavior.